# how to use keras demo code siamese_contrastive.py to use a custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, siamese-network

I am following this example [Image similarity estimation using a Siamese Network with a contrastive loss](https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_contrastive/).

The given code snippet reads directly from `keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`.

I am trying to adapt this example and trying to feed a **new dataset**. I have a directory where I kept examples of positive and negative images.

So I have three directories of `anchor`, `positive`, and `negative` examples, i.e.:

```
anchor/
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
....
```

```
positive/
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
....
```

```
negative/
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
....
```

How could I feed this dataset into this model?

For my case I have to get embedding of the images before feeding into the model. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can load images like this :

```
anchor_images = sorted([str(anchor_images_path / f) for f in os.listdir(anchor_images_path)])
```

Same for positives and negatives.

**Detailed example here:**

https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_network/